# Wpf flowdocumentReader page turn effect

Tags: wpf, flowdocumentreader

I am working in a very crucial wpf project.This project is almost finished apart from some points.

I am showing flowdocumentreader which is loaded with dynamic images  around 100.
I have one requirement to show page turn effect whenever user navigates to pages in flowdocumentreader.

I have used google and seen lots of example but no body has used flowdocumentreader.

I have also seen wpfBookControl which is not dynamic and it uses xps document.

Please help me to achieve that.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/b1ac8f73-41b7-4602-ac61-286f1a00b607) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2273677/wpf-magic-negating-brush).

In the [WPF Shader Effects Library](http://fx.codeplex.com/) you have a 'negative' effect which inverts ('turns') the image.

Comment: Sorry ,it doesnot show the page turn effect.It shows only the image blurring effect.

Comment: The WPF Shader FX Lib definitely does it. it's called negate. Unless I don't understand what you wanna do.